# Join Firestore Collections, Typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to join 2 Firestore documents which have the same unique id: `avatar_id`

The documents are like this:

Menus:

```
 { "name": "kafe", "avatar_id": "XPuDx5P3M3Ctlb2jQDh8", "price": 50 }
```

Menu:

```
{ "avatar_id": "XPuDx5P3M3Ctlb2jQDh8", "image":"someImage.jpeg" }
```

I created a helper to join these documents:

```
import { AngularFirestore } from '@angular/fire/firestore';

import { combineLatest, pipe, of, defer } from 'rxjs';
import { map, switchMap, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';

export const leftJoin = (
  afs: AngularFirestore,
  field: string | number,
  collection: string,
  limit = 100
) => {
return (source: any) =>
defer(() => {
  // Operator state
  let collectionData: any;

  // Track total num of joined doc reads
  let totalJoins = 0;

  return source.pipe(
    switchMap(data => {
      // Clear mapping on each emitted val ;

      // Save the parent data state
      collectionData = data as any[];

      const reads$ = [];

      for (const doc of collectionData) {
        // Push doc read to Array

        if (doc[field]) {
          // Perform query on join key, with optional limit
          const q = (ref: any) => ref.where(field, '==', doc[field]).limit(limit);
          
          console.log(doc[field]);

          reads$.push(afs.collection(collection, q).valueChanges());
        } else {
          reads$.push(of([]));
        }
      }

      return combineLatest(reads$);
    }),
    map(joins => {
      return collectionData.map((v: any, i: any) => {
        totalJoins += joins[i].length;
        return { ...v, [collection]: joins[i] || null };
      });
    }),
    tap(final => {
      console.log(
        `Queried ${(final as any).length}, Joined ${totalJoins} docs`
      );
      totalJoins = 0;
    })
  );
 });
};
```

and then in the `component.ts`

```
this.express = this.af.collection('menus')
  .doc('cid')
  .collection('express')
  .valueChanges()
  .pipe(
    leftJoin(af, 'avatar_id', 'menu', 5),
    shareReplay(1)
  )
}
```

the problem is that the result is: `{ "name": "kafe", "avatar_id": " XPuDx5P3M3Ctlb2jQDh8", "price": 50, "menu": [] }` meaning that the menu is empty, instead i expect to be `{ "name": "kafe", "avatar_id": " XPuDx5P3M3Ctlb2jQDh8", "price": 50, "menu": ["avatar_id": "XPuDx5P3M3Ctlb2jQDh8", "image":"someImage.jpeg"] }`.

Any help what I'm doing wrong? I'm quite new to this subject.

Comment: @JSmith what do you mean by source data

Comment: @sorry I just saw the data at the beginning, also I'm some questions here are the two data on the same path in the database?

Comment: @JSmith menus: `/menus/L62011002A/express`, menu: `/menu/XPuDx5P3M3Ctlb2jQDh8`. they are diferent collections in different paths

Comment: I am going to try to write an answer but I'won't be using the same way as you are doing

Comment: @JSmith thank you very much, I appreciate

Comment: I've tried but it's hard have you tested it on only two records or many more?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226216/discussion-between-jsmith-and-erjon).

Comment: [stackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-uzwfze?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) looks like it is fine? Not exactly what you asked but yeah the `avatar` field is populated

Comment: This worked great for me. Combining Users and Vehicles to create a table that is exported to excel. For some reason, I get holes in my data though (i.e. about half of the records don't show), but only on some tenants, which I guess indicates there is more of an issue with the data than the code. 

Thanks again.